# C++ Filling empty arrays in void function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

For class I had to write a program that calculated 12 different "grades".  I used 2 different arrays - "numerator[ ]" and "denominator[ ]" which each have a size of 12 (12 different ints).  For this assignment, I had to make the value of 3 of the denominators 0, which indicated that the corresponding numerator to those denominators equaled "bonus points" (example- grade 5/0 would equal 5 bonus points).  However, now I have to create a "data cleanup" function, which takes all the scores with non-zero denominators, and move them into a new empty array (leaving me with only "real" scores, which I made as newNumerator[ ], and newDenominator[ ], as well as the new size of each array "newSize".  The data cleanup function needs to have these parameters-

```
dataClean(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size, int newNumerator[], int newDenominator[], int &newSize)
```

I need to populate the new arrays and define newSize of those arrays within the cleanData function, and to have their new values come back to main() through the parameters.  However, I have been stuck on this part for quite some time.  I am not sure if I need to use pointers or not, and even so I am very unclear on how to use them.  Sorry if this is unclear, this assignment has been very confusing to me.  Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need any further clarification for anything.

data file of numerators and denominators (data.txt)

```
72 49 23 5 9 10 6 16 26 54 4 55//numerator[]
75 50 25 0 10 0 0 20 30 55 5 60//denominator[]
```

program-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

typedef int arrayType[];

void readData(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size);
void reportData(arrayType, arrayType, int);
void reportOverall(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size);
void cleanData(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size, int newNumerator[], int newDenominator[], int &newSize);
int main()
{
    const int size = 12;
    int numerator[size];
    int denominator[size];
    int newSize = 12;
    int newNumerator[newSize];
    int newDenominator[newSize];


    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);

    readData(numerator, denominator, size);

    reportData(numerator, denominator, size);

    reportOverall(numerator, denominator, size);

    cout << "\n******************************\n";

    cleanData(numerator, denominator, size, newNumerator, newDenominator, &newSize);
    reportData(newNumerator, newDenominator, newSize);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void readData(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size)
{
    ifstream dataIn;
    dataIn.open("data.txt");
    if(!dataIn)
    {
        cout << "File not found\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    int count;
    for(count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        dataIn >> numerator[count];
    }
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        dataIn >> denominator[count];
    }

    dataIn.close();
}

void reportData(arrayType numerator, arrayType denominator, int size)
{
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        if (denominator[count] == 0)
        {
            cout << "Score " << (count + 1) << " is " << numerator[count] << "/" << denominator[count] << " = " << "Bonus points!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            double percent = 100.0 * static_cast<double>(numerator[count]) / denominator[count];
            cout << "Score " << (count + 1) << " is " << numerator[count] << "/" << denominator[count] << " = " << (percent) << "%\n";
        }
    }
}

void reportOverall(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size)
{
    int count;
    int totalNumerator = 0.0;
    int totalDenominator = 0.0;

    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        totalNumerator += numerator[count];
    }
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        totalDenominator += denominator[count];
    }

    double overallPercent = 100.0 * static_cast<double>(totalNumerator) / (totalDenominator);
    cout << "Total Points Earned (numerators): " << totalNumerator << endl;
    cout << "Total Points Possible (denominators): " << totalDenominator << endl;
    cout << "Overall Grade: " << overallPercent << "%\n";
}

void cleanData(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size, int *newNumerator[], int *newDenominator[], int &newSize)
{
    int count;

    for(count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        int count2 = 0;
        if(denominator[count] != 0)
        {
            *newNumerator[count2] = numerator[count];
            *newDenominator[count2] = denominator[count];
            newSize--;
            count2++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: I am not too sure, but the build always fails.  I cant seem to get the call to cleanData to match the function definition, and if I do I get a strange error-  "cleanData(int*, int*, int, int*, int*, int)", referenced from:       _main in LabK_Zizzi.o     ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to fix the function call and cleanData defintion with proper referencing of parameters

```
within main:

cleanData(numerator, denominator, size, newNumerator, newDenominator, newSize);


void cleanData(int* numerator, int* denominator, const int size, int *newNumerator, int *newDenominator, int newSize)
{
int count;

    for(count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        int count2 = 0;
        if(denominator[count] != 0)
        {
            newNumerator[count2] = numerator[count];
            newDenominator[count2] = denominator[count];
            newSize--;
            count2++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  fixed my problem instantly.